# How to install Alchemist on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I install the [Alchemist](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist) gem?

I have added `gem 'alchemist'` to my Gemfile

`bundle install`

then I try 10.miles.to.kilometers and get an error: `undefined method`miles'`

according to [alchemist](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist) I have to add `Alchemist.setup` somewhere. Where do I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the gem, but you can try to put it in an initializer, ie  in `config/initializers/alchemist.rb`:

```
Alchemist.setup
```

Restart your app after you have added this file.

Comment: ok. it worked. but now i get the output: 16093.44 from `10.miles.to.kilometers` when i expect `16.0934` any idea?

Comment: It looks like you got meters in stead of kilometers? Diving into the source code of the gem, I found this in `data/units.yml`: `:mile: 1609.344`. You should ask the gem author if that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your second problem. If you call `to_f` on an `Alchemist::Measurement` it gives you the value in terms of the base (in this case meters). If you want to get the number of kilometers you need to call `value` on it:

```
irb(main):005:0> 10.miles.to.kilometers.value
=> 16.09344
```

There might be a useful discussion on if I should change these if they are confusing.